# Change style using JS in VBA Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, css, vba, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need change style in hidden select to block using JavaScript:

I have:

```
<select name="supplierId" style="width: 510px;display: none;">
```

I want change this "display: none" to "display: block", but i don't have any clue how to do it in JS.
I've try

```
    cd.ExecuteScript ("document.querySelector(select[name='supplierId']).style.display = 'block'")
```

or:

```
'cd.ExecuteScript ("getElementByName(supplierId).style.display = block")
```

But... well, no effect. Could anyone can help, please :(

Comment: try adding quotes inside CSS selector throughout, and escape them, e.g.: `cd.ExecuteScript ("document.querySelector(\"select[name='supplierId']\").style.display = 'block'")`

Comment: Nope :( It didn't work for me. I've got a JS-Error.
**JavaScriptError
javascript error: Invalid or unexpected token
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=110.0.5481.77 (65ed616c6e8ee3fe0ad64fe83796c020644d42af-refs/branch-heads/5481@{#839}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.19044 x86_64)**

Comment: right, try doublequotes: `cd.ExecuteScript ("document.querySelector(""select[name='supplierId']"").style.display = 'block'"`. The point is, selector is problably not correct.. try run it on the page itself